# Apex classes should escape variables merged in DML query (rule: Security-ApexSOQLInjection) - how to fix this?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

There is one warning (mention above) in one line, please tell me how to fix?

```java
public with sharing class VIT_CustomLookupController {
    // Method to fetch lookup search result   
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<sObject> fetchLookupData(string searchKey , string sObjectApiName) {    
        List < sObject > returnList = new List < sObject > ();
        string sWildCardText = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        string sQuery = 'Select Id,Name From ' + sObjectApiName + ' Where Name Like : sWildCardText order by createdDate DESC LIMIT 5';
        for (sObject obj: database.query(sQuery)) { // WARNING IN THIS LINE
            returnList.add(obj);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take the [Mitigate SOQL Injection](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/it/content/learn/modules/secure-serverside-development/mitigate-soql-injection) trailhead. It lists several ways to prevent such issue.

You already binded apex variable in the WHERE clause, so you've done almost everything right, to remove the warning, you should use [`String.escapeSingleQuotes(query)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_escapeSingleQuotes) to sanitize user-supplied input.

```java
public static List<sObject> fetchLookupData(String searchKey, String sObjectApiName) {    
    List<sObject> returnList = new List <sObject> ();
    String sWildCardText = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    String sQuery = 'Select Id,Name From ' + sObjectApiName + ' Where Name Like : sWildCardText order by createdDate DESC LIMIT 5';
    for (sObject obj: Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(sQuery))) { // no more warning
        returnList.add(obj);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm)

> This method adds the escape character (`\`) to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings, instead of database commands

Comment: To be pedantic, `sObjectApiName` should be escaped directly, not the entire query. While it works here by accident, it wouldn't work if the query itself contained quotes, like `AND Name = 'Demo'`, as an arbitrary example.